# Получение коэффициентов с биржи ставок betfair средствами python

Tags: python

Сразу оговорюсь, что я не являюсь программистом и делаю проект исключительно для личного использования. Прошу учесть это, если мои вопросы или пояснения будут несколько наивны или ошибочны.
Я занимаюсь ставками на лошадиные скачки в Великобритании и для анализа данных мне пришлось освоить (в пределах, необходимых для решения конкретных задач, по мере их возникновения) язык программирования Python.
Итак, суть проекта.
1.  С нескольких сайтов я получаю прогнозы коэффициентов на лошадей на сегодняшний день (betting forecast), после их обработки и приведения к нужному мне виду я сохраняю их в отдельные КСВ-файлы.
2.  С помощью pandas провожу сравнение датафреймов из полученных csv-файлов с биржевыми коэффициентами, актуальными на момент запуска программы (биржа ставок Betfair), и сохраняю лошадей с коэффициентами на них, подходящих под определённые критерии, в отдельный csv-файл (исходные файлы автоматически удаляются после формирования итогового файла, чтобы не засорять диск).
3.  На следующий день повторяю процедуру, получая в итоге файл с ежедневными отборами, подходящими под нужные мне критерии.
Первую часть решил с использованием библиотек requests, Beautiful Soup и csv, освоив их в степени, необходимой для получения html интересующих меня страниц, их обработки и получения нужных мне данных в нужном формате.
Со второй частью сначала вроде тоже всё получилось, поскольку биржевые коэффициенты я получал не непосредственно с биржи ставок Betfair, а с сайта www.oddschecker.com, на котором для каждого забега есть коэффициенты с разных букмекерских контор и бирж, в том числе и с нужного мне Betfair. После их обработки с помощью pandas я смог получить тот результат, на который рассчитывал изначально.
Но со временем я обнаружил, что коэффициенты, которые позиционируются там как коэффициенты биржи Betfair, по большей части отличаются от коэффициентов, которые имеются непосредственно на бирже, что существенно искажает результат, так как в этом моменте мне нужна абсолютная точность.
И вот, собственно, проблема: когда я попытался получить коэффициенты непосредственно с сайта https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/ (чтобы увидеть коэффициенты просто в браузере, авторизация не нужна), я столкнулся с тем, что html этой страницы фактически не содержит этих данных, и они генерируются лишь после соответствующего нажатия на ссылку конкретного забега.
Как я понял, это реализовано путём создания js-запроса при нажатии на ссылку, и получения ответа с данными, которые актуальны для этого конкретного забега.
Прошу помочь и ответить на следующие вопросы:
1.  Возможно ли получение нужных мне коэффициентов средствами python?
2.  Если да – то какие библиотеки мне нужно изучить для этого и на какие их функции или классы посоветуете обратить основное внимание для решения моей задачи?

Comment: я бы сказал в вопросе очень много лишней информации. Коротко - советую открыть консоль отладки в браузере и посмотреть запросы к API бекжнда. Потом можете просто повторить запрос, используя например curl. (к сожалению на сайт зайти не могу, заблокирован в РФ).

Comment: @Vladimir Nikitin в первую очередь можно попытаться поймать Ajax запросах, их можно увидеть в режиме разработчика в любом браузере. Если же вы не можете его определить, то единственный способ спарсить данные, которые написаны на Javacript, это работать через сам браузер, чтобы он обработал Javascript и сгенерировал HTML - структуру. Для этого вы можете использовать Selenium Webdriver с любым удобным для вас браузером, только не забудьте установить необходимый webdriver для браузера. К сожалению этот способ намного медленнее и тяжелее, чем просто спарсить библиотекой lxml или bs4

Comment: , который вы использовали,

Comment: Можете посмотреть код у меня в репозитории, например, тут https://github.com/danilshik/Parsers/blob/develop/compubench.com_gfxbench.com/compubench.com.py, вам нужен метод Init, как инициализируется браузер, и как искать элементы в методе parse.

Answer (score 1):

Это задачка для селениума (+lxml/bs). Сам сейчас подобный парсер пытаюсь написать.
Вот пример получения данных из этой страницы (например, строка 1)
https://www.betfair.com/sport/horse-racing/meeting?eventId=29141406&dayToSearch=20190221
Вывод не форматировал. Это сами уже

```
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml
from lxml.html import parse

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.betfair.com/sport/horse-racing/meeting?eventId=29141406&dayToSearch=20190221')
page = browser.page_source
# time.sleep(3)
browser.quit()

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(page)
row = doc.cssselect(".runner-body")[0]
for i in row:
    print(i.text_content().strip())
```

Результат

```
Номер
3


Ничья
-SilkЛошадь/Последние результаты

Robin Deuz Pois

444232Жокей/Инструктор
Paddy Brennan 
Paul WebberВозраст
7Вес/(ИЛИ)

11-6
(93)Оборудование
cp3.0Победа или победа/место
  3.25    СЦ
```